# Cannot get MVC working in asp.net web forms project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm taking over a solution from a previous developer.  In it are two projects.  Both started as web forms.  He added mvc to the one project and it works.  I added mvc to the other one and no matter what I do I get 404s for all of my routing.  I've compared everything I can think of between the two projects, spent the last day googling for an answer and can't figure out why it isn't working.  This is running in visual studio 2017 with iisexpress, mvc 5.2.3.

Here's my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd"></glimpse>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30720" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpModules>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <tagMapping>
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
        <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
      </tagMapping>
    </pages>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <!-- Glimpse: This can be commented in to add additional data to the Trace tab when using WebForms
        <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" enabled="true" pageOutput="false"/> -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allasmx}", new { allasmx = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
    routes.IgnoreRoute("");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by adding this class to the Areas>API folder.

```
public class APIAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName => "API";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "API",
            "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```